# Gradle exec python file that use other files: permission denied

Tags: java, python, gradle, exec

I’m trying to execute the MCP’s decompile.bat file using gradle exec: https://hasteb.in/raquwide.gradle. The decompile.bat execute the runtime/decompile.py file.
But I receive a permission error: https://hasteb.in/irixucot

I also tested the decompile.sh script: same error.
This error doesn’t occur when I execute the decompile.bat or the decompile.sh.

I'm running it on Windows so I can't use `chmod`.

More code can be found in the latest MCP version in the runtime folder.

MCP workspace:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/in9wuyxx2xat4k0/MCPTest.zip/file

Could you help me ?

Comment: Please share any code/data as text in the post itself, not as images.

Comment: @AMC Hi, I edited my post. I linked my workspace. I don't know what data is missing now. If you need something, reply me !